# Facebook login in android and IOS and server side, which way is best?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, android-facebook

I want to integrate Facebook login from my android and IOS app, and there is Nodejs server at backed, 
As I know we can do FB login in two ways 
 1. Server side(by providing FB login API's through API server) 
 2. Mobile side, by directly using Fb client libraries for Android and IOS

so my question is FB login integration is best at server side or mobile side?